# Load JSON in Datatables

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I would like to update a datatable via JSON, this is the code I am using:

datatable initialization:

```
$(function () {
//Migliorata la leggibilita con classe nowrap - datatable
$('#datatable1').DataTable({
    'columns': [
        {'data':'cognome'},
        {'data':'nome'},
        {'data':'descrizione'},
        {'data':'totale'},
        {'data':'saldo'},
    ],
    'paging'        : false,
    'lengthChange'  : true,
    'searching'     : false,
    'ordering'      : false,
    //'order'           : [[3, 'desc']],
    'info'          : true,
    'autoWidth'     : true,
    'deferRender'   : true,
    'scrollX'       : true,
    'language': {
        'lengthMenu':   'Visualizza _MENU_ fatture per pagina',
        'zeroRecords':  'Nessuna riga trovata',
        'search':       'Cerca',
        'info':         ' ',
        'infoEmpty':    ' ',
        'infoFiltered': '(Filtro su _MAX_ record totali)',
        'paginate': {
            'previous': 'Precedente',
            'next':     'Successiva'
        }
    }
});
});
```

this instead is the code I use on autocomplete jquery to dynamically choose and load the datatable

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
serviceUrl: '/app/production/pages/fatturabianca/service.php',
minChars: 2,
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    var stringa_referente = suggestion.value;
    var dati_ref = stringa_referente.split(' - ');
    var cod_ref = dati_ref[0];
    var tipo_ricerca = dati_ref[2];
    
    var tipo_rif = $("#rif").val();
    if(tipo_rif == "Scuola")
        urlTable = 'populate_table.php?id_ref='+cod_ref;
    else
        urlTable = 'populate_tableS.php?id_ref='+cod_ref;       
    
    $.ajax({
        url:urlTable,
        method:'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            
            var table = $('#datatable1').DataTable();
            table.clear().draw();
            table.row.add(json).draw();
            
            //window.location.href = "visualizza_fatture.php";
            //window.location.reload();
            //alert(JSON.stringify(json));
        }
    });
}
});
```

In the console JSON looks like

[image]

but when I call the statement table.row.add (json) .draw (); I get the following error:

[image]

any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you gone through the troubleshooting steps on that link?

Comment: yes, i have seen the possible resolutions, but my html table has the same columns as the columns definition, no colspan or rowspan rule and the json result is correct. I don't use columns.defaultcontent ...

Comment: Do you need to pass in json.data instead of just json? You may also need to call rows.add() instead of row.add() since you're trying to pass multiple rows. https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

Comment: It works...i used table.rows.add(json.data).draw(); thank you for your suggestion @Charles Bamford